# Create an interactive Shell prompt menu from a dynamic list?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, shell, scripting

The following prompt should allow the user to make a selection based on the populated list that is outputted to an array, then prints the list with its index, and asks user to select a number from the list, then sets it to a variable. Only one choice is allowed, if user specifies an incorrect option, the script will prompt to select a correct number.

```
Multiple devices detected, please select one from the list:
1. Device1
2. Device2
3. Device3

1
You have selected device Device1
```

The code below is not functional and has many syntax errors, first I would like the script to detect if the output of `arr=($(ip ad|awk '/state UP/ {print $2}'))` contains multiple entries, if so run the script, otherwise set a default value.
The case statement is not dynamic however, if more then 2 cases like below it will fail, perhaps a loop?

```
host_interfaces()
{
   arr=($(ip ad|awk '/state UP/ {print $2}'))
   echo "Multiple devices detected, please select one from the list:"
   for i in "${!arr[@]}"; do
   printf "%s%s\n" "$i.  " "${arr[$i]}"
   done
   PS3='Please enter your choice: '
   select opt in "${arr[@]}"
   do
      case $opt in
            "$opt")
               echo "You have selected device $opt"
               export HOST_INTERFACE=$opt
               ;;
            *) echo "invalid option
               break
               ;;
      esac
   done
}
```

Comment: `${#arr[@]}` expands as the number of entries in the array. So `[ "${#arr[@]}" -eq 1 ]` maybe the test you are looking for.

Comment: I am not sure I understand all details. What do you want to do when your user selects a valid choice? Continue asking for a choice or stop there? Same question when the choice is not valid or when the choice corresponds to `Quit`.

Comment: Try `dialog/whiptail`

Comment: @RenaudPacalet When the user selects a valid choice, the value is set to HOST_INTERFACE and the function end. I removed "Quit" as it was part of a example code snippet, so the only options are either a valid choice from array, or invalid choice.

Comment: @Kev OK, I updated my answer accordingly. Please edit your question and modify it to reflect your real specifications (SO is also useful to other visitors with similar problems, it is thus important that the questions are very clear and accurate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, maybe?

```sh
host_interfaces()
{
  local opt='' h=''
  arr=($(ip ad|awk '/state UP/ {print $2}'))
  if [ "${#arr[@]}" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "One single device detected"
    h="${arr[0]}"
  elif [ "${#arr[@]}" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Multiple devices detected, please select one from the list:"
    PS3='Please enter your choice: '
    select opt in "${arr[@]}"
    do
      case "$opt" in
        "")
          echo "Invalid choice"
          h=''
          ;;
        *)
          echo "You have selected device $opt"
          h="$opt"
          break
          ;;
      esac
    done
  else
    echo "No device detected"
  fi
  echo "Selected device: ${h:-none}"
  export HOST_INTERFACE="$h"
  [ -z "$h" ] && return 1 || return 0
}
```

Note that the function returns 1 if no valid device was found or selected, else 0. So you can use it with:

```sh
if host_interfaces; then
  echo "HOST_INTERFACE = $HOST_INTERFACE"
else
  echo "No device selected"
fi
```

Comment: Why use local? Is it so you can simply create a variable that is local in scope, because its value is exported to HOST_INTERFACE, so it has no use outside the scope of the function? And that memory can be freed, therby making the script more efficient?

Comment: `${h:-none}"` What is the purpose of `":-none"`?

Comment: The role of `local` is the same as in many programming languages: limiting the scope. Local variables have no visibility outside their scope, which is good programming practice. `${h:-none}` expands as `none` if `h` is unset or null. Note: all this is very well documented in the bash manual. If you are learning bash programming, I strongly encourage you to start using the manual (`man bash`) as your main reference. It is well written, well organized, searchable... If you search `:-` your first hit is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you! Will use it as a point of reference going forward.

Answer (score 0):

A solution:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

declare HOST_INTERFACE=

function host_interfaces() {
    local -a arr=($(ip ad | awk '/state UP/ {gsub(/:/, "", $2); print $2}'))
    if [ "${#arr[@]}" -eq 1 ]; then
        HOST_INTERFACE="${arr[0]}"
        return 0
    fi
    local opt=
    HOST_INTERFACE=
    echo "Multiple devices detected, please select one from the list:"
    PS3='Please enter your choice: '
    # Add "Quit" value to the items
    select opt in "${arr[@]}" Quit; do
        # "opt" does not contains the number but the associated value
        case $opt in
            "Quit")
                # 
                break
            ;;
            "")
                # No value found
                echo "invalid option"
            ;;
            *)
                echo "You have selected device $opt"
                export HOST_INTERFACE=$opt
                break
            ;;
        esac
    done
}

host_interfaces
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simply use [dialog](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) here.

[image]

```
dialog --backtitle "Device selection" --title "Multiple devices detected" --menu "please select one from the list:" 10 45 4 1 "Device1" 2 "Device2" 3 "Device3"
```

See `man dialog`

Comment: Thank you @NVRM but I was looking for a solution on the command line as this would be part of a larger script, editing the question so it is more clear.